# Real time app with control panel to handle other web by node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, real-time

I'm trying to do a real time app with a control panel where after pressing a button other page do something at the same time.
I've tried using node.js and socket.io with 2 namespaces, one for index and other for panel,  but the documentation is not very clear and I didn't find a solution.

The function Enable() or Disable() emit the message, however 'panel.on' don't receive the message 'button' on server.js. I need some help about what I'm doing wrong or another possible solution to face my real time app.
Many thanks.

My code is:

```
//Server.js

//Creation of socket
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var sock;

app.listen(8001, function(){
 console.log('listening on *.8001');
});

//Creation of namespaces 
var index = io.of('/index');
index.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected'):
});


var panel = io.of('/panel');
panel.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected'):
});

function handler (req, res) {
  //console.log(res);
  console.log(req.url);

  switch(req.url) {

    case "/panel.html":
        fs.readFile('panel.html', function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading panel.html');
          }
          res.writeHead(200);
          res.end(data);
        });
        break;

    default:
        fs.readFile('index.html',
        function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
          }
          res.writeHead(200);
          res.end(data);
        });
  }

}

panel.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');
  sock = socket;

  panel.on('button', function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    if (data == 'enable'){

        index.emit('buttonstatus', 'enabled');        

    }else if(data == 'disable'){

        index.emit('buttonstatus', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});

//index.html
...

<script src = "http://localhost:8001/socket.io/socket.io.js" >
<script>

var socket = io(http://localhost:8001/index);
socket.on('buttonstatus', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data == 'enabled'){          
          console.log("buttonstatus enabled");        

    }else if (data == 'disabled') {
        console.log("buttonstatus disabled");
    }
});

</script>

//panel.html

...

<input type="button" name="enable" id="enableButton" value="enable" onClick="Enable();">
<input type="button" name="disable" id="disableButton" value="disable" onClick="Disable();">
<script src = "http://localhost:8001/socket.io/socket.io.js" >
<script>
  var socket = io(http://localhost:8001/panel);

  function Enable(){
      socket.emit('button', 'enable');

  }
  function Disable(){
      socket.emit('button', 'disable');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: yeah their documentation is not that clear. I found it helpful to follow their chat tutorial http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ and the code for the tutorial https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat

Comment: I had seen the examples but I didn't see this carefully. I returned to plan the app and following the chat example, I joined the control with the page to manage. Now, it works! Many Thanks for your orientation and help!